# Tomcat security Manager - Determining what permissions are needed for a web app

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a very large web application that I would like to publish specifications on what permissions are needed to be granted for "Tomcat Security Manager" to work properly with the web application.

Is there any automatic way to run the web application and generate a list of all the permissions that are needed?

I've tried doing this manually by enabling Tomcat Security Manager and working my way through the security exceptions and adding the needed permissions. The problem with this, however, is that only one security exception is shown at a time and after every exception I need to update the catalina.policy, restart Tomcat and move to the next exception.

I have literally spent 2hrs doing this without any hint of being close to complete. There has to be a better way.

[Tomcat Security Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question.

Adding the following Java option to Tomcat will create an entry in stderr for every permission that is needed:

-Djava.security.debug=all

I'm not sure why I didn't find this before, but its documented in the Tomcat 6.0 manual.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I have a large web application as well that runs the Tomcat Security Manager and the only time there were permission issues is when Tomcat was already deployed, stopped, had the security switch added, and then restarted.

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/path/to/my/application-" {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission "IPAddress:Port", "connect";
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
```

`};`

Is exactly how I resolved it.  You can replace `/path/to/my/application` with something like this `/webapps/mySuperAwesomeApplication`

Comment: The end goal isn't just to get the application running, but to document what permissions need to be enabled to get it running. Unfortunately, enabling all permissions like you did with your entry:

permission java.security.AllPermission;

Doesn't help me that much. Yes, it allows things to work, but that's pretty much like saying "Why don't you disable Tomcat Security Manager". The environments where they want Tomcat Security Manager enabled is also the same environments where giving "all permissions", is not something they would allow.

Comment: Actually it does prevent people from mucking up the information, this sounds like a STIG requirement imho.

Comment: What you've suggested is just like having Tomcat Security Manager disabled for your web application. If someone's going to have a requirement that it is enabled, they're most likely not going to want "all permissions" allowed for the web application. 

For example, if there was a directory traversal bug in the web application, adding "all permissons" would not contain this issue. If on the other hand you could grant access only to the file paths needed, it would contain this issue. This is the purpose of Tomcat Security Manager.

Comment: My goal is to properly define what the web application needs in proper operation to give it enough access to function. By enabling Tomcat Security Manager this will limit the affects of any discovered vulnerabilities that may allow an attacker a way to attempt to accomplish more than the designed functionality.

Comment: @Doug if you dig into the security manager on Tomcat you will see how truly useless it is.  It is security theater at its finest.

Answer (score 0):

What about using -Djava.security.debug=fail ?